# appengine static_files not found by handler

Tags: google-app-engine

```
application: fooapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/upload

- url: /lib
  static_dir : static/lib

- url: /resources
  static_dir : static/resources

- url: /foo.js
  static_files : static/foo.js
  upload: static/upload
```

With the above config, I was able to launch the app in localhost using dev_appserver.py. It localhost:8080 served index.html inside static folder.
However when I deployed the app, fooapp.appspot.com results in 404. I see below message in logs.
**Static file referenced by handler not found: static/index.html**

[image: project structure]
Why is the index.html file not served after deploy? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the yaml to below worked.

```
application: fooapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /lib
  static_dir : static/lib

- url: /resources
  static_dir : static/resources

- url: /app.js
  static_files : static/app.js
  upload: static/app.js

- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html
```